# Error : Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped in ios(swift)

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController, UIWebViewDelegate {

var myWebView: UIWebView = UIWebView()
var url: String?

func configureView() {
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.
    if let url = self.url {
        var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(url)
        var urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        self.myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.myWebView.frame    = self.view.bounds
    self.myWebView.delegate = self
    self.view.addSubview(self.myWebView)

    self.configureView()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func setDetailItem(url: String?) {
    self.url = url
    self.configureView()
}

func webView(webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWithRequest request: NSURLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
    return true
}
}
```

> Value of optional type 'NSURL?' not unwrapped; did you mean to use '!'
>   or '?'?'

is the message in the line :
`var url: NSURL = NSURL.URLWithString(url)`

Whats wrong with my code?
I tried to input `!`, even `?`, but these methods didn't help.

Comment: No, it's not a way, I've already tried.

Answer (score 2):

Use an NSURL constructor instead of the `NSURL.URLWithString`:

```
var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: self.url)!
```

And don´t define url two time as different `String`s and one time as a `NSURL`:

```
func configureView() {
    if let urlStr = self.url {
        let myURL: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlStr)!
        let urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: myURL)
        self.myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Really thank you! I tried this way, but when I launch the app and tap on any cell, the console says (lldb) and the line "var urlRequest: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)" gives Thread 1: breakpoint 1.1

Comment: @КириллКрайнов Then you are doing something else wrong - see the image I added to the question.

Answer (score 1):

It *is* the way, but you have to fix your code a little bit: don't use the same variable name for different purposes,unwrap what you need to, and use the right init for NSURL.

```
func configureView() {
    if let url = self.url {
        var newUrl = NSURL(string: url)
        var urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: newUrl!)
        self.myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The Swift equivalent of `[NSURL URLWithString: …]` is `NSURL(string: …)`

be careful with potential ambiguity of variable names (url).
The `if` line unwraps both optionals

```
var urlString : String?

func configureView() {
  // Update the user interface for the detail item.
  if let urlValue = self.urlString, url = NSURL(string: urlValue) {
    let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    self.myWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
  }
}
```